# How to add AdView from AdMob to a ListView

Tags: android, admob

I'm confused at how to make adview from admob work with a listview. I'm new to ads and have just finished the basic tutorial but now trying to put in in my own app. I have some things commented out that I tried to do to begin with.

```
        // Create the adView
    AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, myID);
    // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it’s been given
    // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
   // LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    // Add the adView to it
    lv.addView(adView);
    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/itemName" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dip" android:text="Test view" 
    android:textSize = "25sp"
    android:singleLine = "true"/>
```

> 04-01 19:28:58.163: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(421): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-01 19:28:58.163: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(421):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{org.demo.textaway2/org.demo.textaway2.TextAway2}:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not
>   supported in AdapterView 04-01 19:28:58.163:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(421):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
>   04-01 19:28:58.163: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(421):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>   04-01 19:28:58.163: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(421):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125) 04-01
>   19:28:58.163: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(421):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   04-01 19:28:58.163: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(421):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 04-01
>   19:28:58.163: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(421):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 04-01 19:28:58.163:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(421):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) 04-01
>   19:28:58.163: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(421):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 04-01
>   19:28:58.163: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(421):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 04-01 19:28:58.163:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(421):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   04-01 19:28:58.163: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(421):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) 04-01
>   19:28:58.163: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(421):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 04-01 19:28:58.163:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(421): Caused by:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not
>   supported in AdapterView 04-01 19:28:58.163:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(421):     at
>   android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:435) 04-01
>   19:28:58.163: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(421):     at
>   org.demo.textaway2.TextAway2.onCreate(TextAway2.java:164) 04-01
>   19:28:58.163: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(421):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   04-01 19:28:58.163: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(421):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
>   04-01 19:28:58.163: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(421):     ... 11 more

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal" android:paddingLeft="5dp"
 android:paddingRight="5dp">

 <TextView android:id="@+id/itemName" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="50dip" android:text="Test view" 
  android:textSize = "25sp"
  android:singleLine = "true"/>
  
</LinearLayout>

Answer (score 2):

The stack trace includes this:

```
addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView
```

Which answers your question - you can't use AdMob in an AdapterView or its subclasses, which you're trying to do. You'll either need to write your own View class to render the list objects, use a different ad service (adwhirl etc - perhaps another doesn't have this limitation) or move the ad(s) outside the list, into a footer/header.

Comment: This is message is about the method `addView`, not the `AdView` widget provided by AdMob.  You can't add any type of widget to a ListView using `addView` because you're supposed to use an adapter to return the views displayed by the list, not add them explicitly.  You can display an AdView widget in a list by writing an adapter that returns an instance of AdView from the `getView` method.